# How to fix background skew in screen recording

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, screencast

I'm currently using an Axon 7 (Android 6.0.1) to record some gameplay using the Google Play recording feature.

While recording in 720p, the quality looks great until there is a lot of movement with my character. For example, in the video below, from 0:25 to 0:27, the background gets extremely blurry because my character is moving.

https://youtu.be/xIBF4AdSl54

Is there a way to fix this? I'm not sure why I have this poor quality. whether it is my phone or the software I'm using, but I've seen other people's videos that have pristine quality throughout their entire video. I've made sure to turn off any powersaving settings as well as keep my phone plugged in during the recording, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: It could be the Google recorder itself. Try a 3rd party one (AZ recorder ain't too bad)

Comment: @DanBrown Worked like a charm. AZ allowed me to increase the bit rate and the quality is a lot better. You can submit this as an answer and I will mark it correct. Thanks a bunch